# How to show a sequence converges uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

How do you show that a sequence does or does not converge uniformly? Consider:

$f_n(x)$ = {0 if x = 0, n if 0 $\lt$ x $\lt$ $1\over{n}$, 0 if $1\over{n}$$\leq$ x $\leq$ 2

I know that for any given x, {$f_n$}$_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to 0. I also know that it converges to 0 faster or slower depending on the x. For example if x = 1, the sequence has already hit 0 at n=1 and it will stay there until infinity. But if x = $1\over{10}$, it won't hit 0 until n = 10.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say. x $\in[0,2]$

Comment: Show $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{x \in [0,2]} |f_n(x) -0| \neq 0$. In this case it is very easy to show.

Comment: So the supremum would equal n right?

Comment: So the limit of the supremums goes to infinity as n goes to infinity

Comment: That is correct.  So we can't have $|f_n(x) - 0| < \epsilon$ for all $x$ no matter how large $n$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly, then $\int f_n \rightarrow \int f$. Since the point-wise limit is $0$, the uniform limit should also be $0$.

Now for any $n$ we have,

$$\int_{0}^2 f_n(x)dx = n\times \frac{1}{n}= 1 \neq 0 = \int_0^2f(x)dx$$

Conclusion?

Comment: You did not say about continuity of $f_n$.

Answer (score 1):

For $n>0,\;\;$  take for example $$x_n=\frac{1}{2n}.$$

we have

$$(\forall n>0)\;\;\; 0<x_n<\frac{1}{n}$$

$\implies$

$$(\forall n>0)\;\;\; f(x_n)=n$$

$\implies$

$$(\forall n>0) \;\;\sup_{x\in[0,2]}|f_n(x)|\geq n$$

$\implies$

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sup_{x\in[0,2]}|f_n(x)-0|=+\infty$$

$\implies$

the sequence of functions  $(f_n)$ doesn't converge uniformly to zero at $[0,2]$

Comment: The supremum for all n would equal n, right, not $\geq$?

Comment: @JohnH Yes, reached at$(0,\frac{1}{n})$.

Comment: So the only way for this to have uniform convergence is for the limit of the supremums to equal 0. correct?

Comment: Yes,  by definition.